# Save data stream to a file every second in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, kinect-sdk

I am reading sensor(kinect) data in the event handler of an event that gets raised when the data is available (at 30 times/sec). I am calculating joint angles from the data.

Up on clicking a button,I need to write joint angle data to file every second(variable) for 5 minutes(variable).

Can some one please point me in right direction on how to accomplish this.

I am using WPF, C#, kinect for widows 2 SDK

Comment: Nice one codeflare! What have you tried so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can simply do System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\data.txt", jointAngles). But I will be saving too much data. I just wanna know how I can write data only once/sec or twice/sec when the data is coming at 30 times/sec and that too only for 5 min.

Comment: average 30 angles then write?

Comment: Can you please show your code for the handling of the event and for the computation of the joint angles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)!

```
static System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

void TimerInit(int interval) {
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick); //this is run every interval
    myTimer.Interval = internal;
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
    myTimer.Start(); 
}

private static void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\path.txt", jointAngles); //You might want to append
    if (reached 5 minutes or X write cycles) {
        myTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `System.Threading.Timer` if you don't want to reference Windows Forms.